# Connect to embedded orientdb server

Tags: orientdb

I have a embedded server with this default config: orientdb-server-config.xml I use version 1.0 from maven.
I'm having trouble connecting to it from the console.

Here is the command I tried: `connect remote:localhost/temp admin admin`

`Disconnecting from the database [null]...OK
Connecting to database [remote:localhost/temp] with user 'admin'...
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.ONetworkProtocolException: Binary protocol is incompatible
 with the Server connected: client=9, server=12`

But I have these listeners:

```
  <listener protocol="binary" port-range="2424-2430" ip-address="0.0.0.0"/>
  <listener protocol="cluster" port-range="2434-2440" ip-address="0.0.0.0"/>
  <listener protocol="http" port-range="2480-2490" ip-address="0.0.0.0">
```

And this storage: `<storage loaded-at-startup="true" userPassword="admin" userName="admin" path="memory:temp" name="temp"/>`

Everything is like the default orientdb-server-config.xml

How do I connect to this embedded database from the console?

Startup output:

```
2012-05-21 06:57:37:496 INFO OrientDB Server v1.0 is starting up... [OServer]
2012-05-21 06:57:38:003 INFO -> Loaded memory database 'temp' [OServer]
2012-05-21 06:57:38:038 INFO Listening binary connections on 0.0.0.0:2424 [OServerNetworkListener]
2012-05-21 06:57:38:039 INFO Listening cluster connections on 0.0.0.0:2434 [OServerNetworkListener]
2012-05-21 06:57:38:040 INFO Listening http connections on 0.0.0.0:2480 [OServerNetworkListener]
2012-05-21 06:57:38:062 INFO OrientDB Server v1.0 is active. [OServer]
```

**UPDATE:** it's working with `[OServer] OrientDB Server v1.0rc9`

**UPDATE2:** the issue was that I had version 1.0 in the server and used the console client from 1.0rc9. But now everything seems ok when server is running 1.0 and i try with client console 1.0. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of updating the question, you should post a response with the solution to your problem.